# How to generate a 360 degre video

Tags: raytracing

Using my raytracing engine, I'd like to generate a 360 degree video which could then be uploaded on Youtube.
By looking on the internet, I couldn't find any specific details about how to do so. I am using FFMPEG to generate short movies.
I saw something about stitching but that didn't really help me that much.

Could you provide me some hints, please ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[YouTube Help: Upload 360-degree videos](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en)

> We recommend uploading  360 videos (equirectangular format with a 2:1 aspect ratio) at a resolution of 7168x3584 or higher, up to 8192x4096.

That means the format uses [Equirectangular projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equirectangular_projection) for capturing the view from all directions to a normal video format with a 2:1 aspect ratio. The projection should translate nicely to a raytracing engine with a simple mapping from pixel coordinates to the ray direction using the formula in the wiki article.